# Can't create a permanent streaming mountpoint using RTSP API (janus)

Tags: video-streaming, janus, janus-gateway

I'm creating an rtsp mountpoint using REST API, this works without a problem, but when I try to make it permanent by passing `"permanent": true` like it says [here](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/streaming.html)  I get the following output from my janus server

```
Creating new session: 1061907600538733; 0x7f287c0051c0
Creating new handle in session 1061907600538733: 7414033818688905; 0x7f287c0051c0 0x7f287c007440
[WARN] No host address for the RTSP video stream, no latching will be performed
[ERR] [config.c:janus_config_save_list:605] Error saving group '5916379136588116' to the config file...
[5916379136588116] New video stream! (ssrc=628656017, index 0)
[7014297744008600] Creating ICE agent (ICE Full mode, controlling)
```

and it adds the mountpoint but it isn't permanent... running janus as root didn't fix it.

Comment: did you resolve it and if so, how?